# Adjective to describe s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶t̶h̶r̶o̶u̶g̶h̶ text?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Sometimes you get <del>strikethrough</del> text that has been *crossed out*.

How can I describe this attribute of text in one word?

i.e.

> The text "<del>the illuminati exists</del>" is ______

Bold, italicised, underlined etc. all fit above; what is the appropriate adjective for striked-through text?

Comment: Note that open compound nouns are still classed as 'nouns'. Some authors ( [Espresso English](https://www.espressoenglish.net/compound-adjectives-in-english/) for instance) are happy to call open compound adjectives 'adjectives': << Use a hyphen when the compound adjective comes BEFORE the noun it modifies, but not when it comes AFTER the noun.

This is a world-famous museum.
This museum is world famous. >>

Comment: The downvote is possibly because the first two forms of your request don't specify that the adjective must be one that can be used in the predicative role.

Comment: You need to change the tense.  Not the text is ...., but *the text **has been** stricken [from the document]*

Comment: I would say "struck out" or "struck through".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any official terms for such a thing, but I'd recommend the likes of 'Stricken/struck', 'crossed-off' or simply struck through.

Comment: +1 I have seen "stricken" used before and was never at a loss for what was implied.

Comment: To quote tchrist, 'We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 
Since it doesn't seem that their is any proper term for it, so I proposed my own possibilities. They can both be used in this sense with people being able to infer what is meant. Therefore, I don't think the likes of references are needed, rather possible words which fit the criteria. This is not opinion in the sense seemingly described by tchrist because of the fact that these words are indeed possible within the context.

Comment: It's opinion because others may think your suggestions poor, as sounding unidiomatic, as being ambiguous ('stricken from the document' means 'removed' rather than 'crossed out'), or because the usages seem to have little pedigree.

Answer (score 1):

For a more common word, I would like to propose ***deleted***.

In HTML syntax, the `del` element ([short for *deleted text*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/del)) is to be used when an edit is made to a document such that some text is considered outdated, irrelevant or incorrect. [From W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/edits.html#the-del-element):

> The del element represents a removal from the document.

When text is placed inside a `del` element, browsers will normally present the affected text by applying a strikethrough effect to it.

In your example, it would be phrased: 'the text [...] *has been* ***deleted***.'

Dictionary entries for ***delete*** also support this usage.

- [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/delete)

> Remove or obliterate (written or printed matter), especially by drawing a line through it

- [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/delete)

> to strike out or remove (something written or printed); cancel; erase; expunge.

- [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/delete)

> to remove or draw a line through something, especially a written word or words

Comment: I believe that this has the same problem [that Edwin Ashworth raised](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/339928/#comment782755_339929) with regard to “stricken” — “deleted” means “removed” rather than “crossed out”. If I can see it and read it, it’s not deleted. Even if it’s unreadable — if it’s “redacted”, like ▒▒▒▒▒▒ — if it’s visible, it’s not deleted. “Marked for deletion” might work, except that’s not a single word.

Answer (score 0):

We can simply say strikethrough text, as strikethrough is often used as a single word.

Please see http://fsymbols.com/generators/strikethrough/

Strikethrough is used as a single word. Please also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikethrough

Comment: "The text is **strikethrough**" - not really `:^/

Comment: But the article seems to use non-standard English, and so is not good to cite as supporting evidence for the usage.